# Calling a subroutine, crashes the program, matrix passing

Tags: fortran, fortran90, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I was writing code to use Fortran Eispack routines (compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors, just to check if the values would be different from the ones I got from Matlab), but every time it calls the qzhes subroutine the program hangs.

I load matrixes from files.

Tried commenting the call, and it works without an issue.

I just learned Fortran, and with the help of the internet I wrote this code  (which compiles and run):

```
program qz
     IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER:: divm, i, divg
INTEGER(kind=4) :: dimen
LOGICAL :: matz
REAL(kind = 8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE:: ma
REAL(kind = 8), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE:: tabm
REAL(kind = 8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE:: ga
REAL(kind = 8), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE:: tabg
REAL(kind = 8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE:: zet

 divm = 1
 divg = 2
 dimen = 20
 matz = .TRUE.
 ALLOCATE(ma(1:dimen,1:dimen))
 ALLOCATE(tabm(1:dimen))
 ALLOCATE(ga(1:dimen,1:dimen))
 ALLOCATE(tabg(1:dimen))

 OPEN(divm, FILE='Em.txt')

 DO i=1,dimen
  READ (divm,*) tabm
  ma(1:dimen,i)=tabm
 END DO

 CLOSE(divm)

 OPEN(divg, FILE='Gje.txt')

 DO i=1,dimen
  READ (divg,*) tabg
  ga(1:dimen,i)=tabg
 END DO

 CLOSE(divg)

 call qzhes(dimen, ma, ga, matz, zet)

 OPEN(divm, FILE='Em2.txt')

 DO i=1,dimen
  tabm = ma(1:dimen,i)
  WRITE (divm,*) tabm
 END DO

 CLOSE(divm)

 OPEN(divg, FILE='Gje2.txt')

 DO i=1,dimen
  tabg = ga(1:dimen,i)
  WRITE (divg,*) tabg
 END DO

 CLOSE(divg)

end program qz 

...//EISPACK subrotines//...
```

Matrixes:

Gje.txt:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxH3QOkswLy_c2hmTGpGVUI3NzQ/view?usp=sharing

Em.txt:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxH3QOkswLy_OEtJUGQwN3ZXX2M/view?usp=sharing

Edit:

```
subroutine qzhes ( n, a, b, matz, z )

!*****************************************************************************80
!
!! QZHES carries out transformations for a generalized eigenvalue problem.
!
!  Discussion:
!
!    This subroutine is the first step of the QZ algorithm
!    for solving generalized matrix eigenvalue problems.
!
!    This subroutine accepts a pair of real general matrices and
!    reduces one of them to upper Hessenberg form and the other
!    to upper triangular form using orthogonal transformations.
!    it is usually followed by QZIT, QZVAL and, possibly, QZVEC.
!
!  Licensing:
!
!    This code is distributed under the GNU LGPL license.
!
!  Modified:
!
!    18 October 2009
!
!  Author:
!
!    Original FORTRAN77 version by Smith, Boyle, Dongarra, Garbow, Ikebe,
!    Klema, Moler.
!    FORTRAN90 version by John Burkardt.
!
!  Reference:
!
!    James Wilkinson, Christian Reinsch,
!    Handbook for Automatic Computation,
!    Volume II, Linear Algebra, Part 2,
!    Springer, 1971,
!    ISBN: 0387054146,
!    LC: QA251.W67.
!
!    Brian Smith, James Boyle, Jack Dongarra, Burton Garbow,
!    Yasuhiko Ikebe, Virginia Klema, Cleve Moler,
!    Matrix Eigensystem Routines, EISPACK Guide,
!    Lecture Notes in Computer Science, Volume 6,
!    Springer Verlag, 1976,
!    ISBN13: 978-3540075462,
!    LC: QA193.M37.
!
!  Parameters:
!
!    Input, integer ( kind = 4 ) N, the order of the matrices.
!
!    Input/output, real ( kind = 8 ) A(N,N).  On input, the first real general
!    matrix.  On output, A has been reduced to upper Hessenberg form.  The
!    elements below the first subdiagonal have been set to zero.
!
!    Input/output, real ( kind = 8 ) B(N,N).  On input, a real general matrix.
!    On output, B has been reduced to upper triangular form.  The elements
!    below the main diagonal have been set to zero.
!
!    Input, logical MATZ, should be TRUE if the right hand transformations
!    are to be accumulated for later use in computing eigenvectors.
!
!    Output, real ( kind = 8 ) Z(N,N), contains the product of the right hand
!    transformations if MATZ is TRUE.
!
  implicit none

  integer ( kind = 4 ) n

  real ( kind = 8 ) a(n,n)
  real ( kind = 8 ) b(n,n)
  integer ( kind = 4 ) i
  integer ( kind = 4 ) j
  integer ( kind = 4 ) k
  integer ( kind = 4 ) l
  integer ( kind = 4 ) l1
  integer ( kind = 4 ) lb
  logical matz
  integer ( kind = 4 ) nk1
  integer ( kind = 4 ) nm1
  real ( kind = 8 ) r
  real ( kind = 8 ) rho
  real ( kind = 8 ) s
  real ( kind = 8 ) t
  real ( kind = 8 ) u1
  real ( kind = 8 ) u2
  real ( kind = 8 ) v1
  real ( kind = 8 ) v2
  real ( kind = 8 ) z(n,n)
!
!  Set Z to the identity matrix.
!
  if ( matz ) then

    z(1:n,1:n) = 0.0D+00

    do i = 1, n
      z(i,i) = 1.0D+00
    end do

  end if
!
!  Reduce B to upper triangular form.
!
  if ( n <= 1 ) then
    return
  end if

  nm1 = n - 1

  do l = 1, n - 1

    l1 = l + 1

    s = sum ( abs ( b(l+1:n,l) ) )

    if ( s /= 0.0D+00 ) then

      s = s + abs ( b(l,l) )
      b(l:n,l) = b(l:n,l) / s

      r = sqrt ( sum ( b(l:n,l)**2 ) )
      r = sign ( r, b(l,l) )
      b(l,l) = b(l,l) + r
      rho = r * b(l,l)

      do j = l + 1, n

        t = dot_product ( b(l:n,l), b(l:n,j) )

        b(l:n,j) = b(l:n,j) - t * b(l:n,l) / rho

      end do

      do j = 1, n

        t = dot_product ( b(l:n,l), a(l:n,j) )

        a(l:n,j) = a(l:n,j) - t * b(l:n,l) / rho

      end do

      b(l,l) = - s * r
      b(l+1:n,l) = 0.0D+00

    end if

  end do
!
!  Reduce A to upper Hessenberg form, while keeping B triangular.
!
  if ( n == 2 ) then
    return
  end if

  do k = 1, n - 2

     nk1 = nm1 - k

     do lb = 1, nk1

        l = n - lb
        l1 = l + 1
!
!  Zero A(l+1,k).
!
        s = abs ( a(l,k) ) + abs ( a(l1,k) )

        if ( s /= 0.0D+00 ) then

        u1 = a(l,k) / s
        u2 = a(l1,k) / s
        r = sign ( sqrt ( u1**2 + u2**2 ), u1 )
        v1 = - ( u1 + r) / r
        v2 = - u2 / r
        u2 = v2 / v1

        do j = k, n
          t = a(l,j) + u2 * a(l1,j)
          a(l,j) = a(l,j) + t * v1
          a(l1,j) = a(l1,j) + t * v2
        end do

        a(l1,k) = 0.0D+00

        do j = l, n
          t = b(l,j) + u2 * b(l1,j)
          b(l,j) = b(l,j) + t * v1
          b(l1,j) = b(l1,j) + t * v2
        end do
!
!  Zero B(l+1,l).
!
        s = abs ( b(l1,l1) ) + abs ( b(l1,l) )

        if ( s /= 0.0 ) then

          u1 = b(l1,l1) / s
          u2 = b(l1,l) / s
          r = sign ( sqrt ( u1**2 + u2**2 ), u1 )
          v1 =  -( u1 + r ) / r
          v2 = -u2 / r
          u2 = v2 / v1

          do i = 1, l1
            t = b(i,l1) + u2 * b(i,l)
            b(i,l1) = b(i,l1) + t * v1
            b(i,l) = b(i,l) + t * v2
          end do

          b(l1,l) = 0.0D+00

          do i = 1, n
            t = a(i,l1) + u2 * a(i,l)
            a(i,l1) = a(i,l1) + t * v1
            a(i,l) = a(i,l) + t * v2
          end do

          if ( matz ) then

            do i = 1, n
              t = z(i,l1) + u2 * z(i,l)
              z(i,l1) = z(i,l1) + t * v1
              z(i,l) = z(i,l) + t * v2
            end do

          end if

        end if

      end if

    end do

  end do

  return
end
```

Comment: My mistake, by "qz" I mean "qzhes". I'll edit and add the subroutine code.

The program crashes by prompting <name> has stopped working.

Comment: Is that the only output or did it print something more before that line?

Comment: Delete the links to your Google drive and copy the input data here. The question must not depend on your file storage where it can be deleted. It must  make sense for future visitors.

Comment: To obtain further information from your program and your compiler, consider using the debug `-g` and warning (`-Wall` for gfortran, for instance) flags.

Comment: Try allocating `zet` before calling `qzhes`.

Answer (score 0):

I would expand the allocation Process

```
integer :: status1, status2, status3, status4, status5
! check the allocation, returnvalue 0 means ok

ALLOCATE(ma(1:dimen,1:dimen), stat=status1)
ALLOCATE(tabm(1:dimen), stat=status2)
ALLOCATE(ga(1:dimen,1:dimen), stat=status3)
ALLOCATE(tabg(1:dimen), stat=status4)
ALLOCATE(zet(1:dimen,1:dimen), stat=status5)
```

And at the end of the Program deallocate all arrays, because, you maybe have no memoryleak now, but if you put this program into a subroutine and use it several time with big matricies during a programrun, the program could leak some serious memory.

```
....

DO i=1,dimen
   tabg = ga(1:dimen,i)
   WRITE (divg,*) tabg
END DO

CLOSE(divg)

DEALLOCATE(ma, stat=status1)
DEALLOCATE(tabm, stat=status2)
DEALLOCATE(ga, stat=status3)
DEALLOCATE(tabg, stat=status4)
DEALLOCATE(zet, stat=status5)
```

You can check again with the status integer, if the deallocation was ok, returnvalue again 0.

Comment: Variables allocated in a subroutine or function are automatically deallocated in the end of the subroutine (unless you use `move_alloc` on them).